# How to write value to localStorage and display it in input on reload?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an input on the page, initially it is empty. I need to implement the following functionality: on page load, the component `App` fetches from `localStorage` a value of key `appData` and puts it in the `input`. That is, so that in the localStorage I write the value to the input and when reloading it is displayed in the input. How can i do this?
**I need to use `useEffect`**

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("Userdata", JSON.stringify(userData));
  }, [userData]);

  return (
    <div>
      <input value={userData} onChange={(e) => setUserData(e.target.value)}></input>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: https://usehooks.com/useLocalStorage/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `change` event to write to the `localStorage`, then use an [init function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state) in the `useState` hook.

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const loadUserData = () => localStorage.getItem('UserData') || '';
const saveUserData = (userData) => localStorage.setItem('UserData', userData);

export default const Application = () => {
  const [ userData, setUserData ] = useState(loadUserData);
   
  const handleUserDataUpdate = e => {
    const userData = e.target.value;
    setUserData(userData);
    saveUserData(userData);
  };
  
  return <div>
    <label htmlFor="testInput">Test Input</label>
    <input id="testInput" value={ userData } onChange={ handleUserDataUpdate } />
  </div>;
}
```

If you need an example using uncontrolled inputs, here is one using `useEffect` :

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const loadUserData = () => localStorage.getItem('UserData') || '';
const saveUserData = (userData) => localStorage.setItem('UserData', userData);

export default const Application = () => {
  const inputRef = useRef();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    inputRef.current.value = loadUserData();
  }, []);  // initial load
  
  const handleUpdateUserData = () => {
    saveUserData(inputRef.current.value);
  };
 
  return <div>
    <label htmlFor="testInput">Test Input</label>
    <input ref={ inputRef } id="testInput" onChange={ handleUpdateUserData } />
  </div>;
}
```

Comment: What if user closes the tab or whole browser while the input is still blurred? The value will be lost.

Comment: @kinduser I have modified my answer, and added an uncontrolled version. Thank you for pointing out the `onBlur` issue. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can set a default value for the input inside `state`.

```
const [userData, setUserData] = 
   useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Userdata')) || '');
```

So when the component mounts (after reload), the initial `userData` value is taken directly from the `localStorage`. If it's empty, the *fallback* value will be set (`''`).

**Note**: Make sure to add also the `onChange` handler to the input.

Comment: `||` will take the second value whenever the first one is *falsy* not just *empty*.  Nullish coalescing operator (`??`) would be a better fit here.

Comment: @marzelin But the input value is always a string, right? So the only _falsy_ string is an empty string. So `??` does not have any effect here.

Comment: I didn't say that using `||` is wrong in this particular example but `??` is generally preferred for creating fallbacks that may save you from a few pesky bugs someday when the type of the value changes for some reason and `''` won't be the only *falsy* value anymore.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, everything works as it should. Only I need to make an example using useEffect. Can you show how this can be done with useEffect?

Comment: @marzelin In case of debugging, yeah maybe you are right. Thanks for it ;)))